# Make a Flex/AIR scroller with an HGroup "snap" to each item when scrolling completes

Tags: flash, apache-flex, mobile, scroll, builder

I'm developing an app for ANDROID devices using Flash Builder Burrito and am having trouble figuring out how to accomplish one aspect of my app.

I have an HGroup inside of a Scroller.  The HGroup has images that are 400px in width and I have the width of each HGroup column set to 400px.  Although the number of items is dynamic, assume I have 10 images in the HGroup.  The width of the Scroller and Viewport is set to 400px.

So far so good -- the user can see a single image within the scroller.  The user can then scroll left or right using touch or mouse and see each image.  But here's where I'm stuck.  I want to make it so that when the user STOPS scrolling the scroller then "snaps" an image into view.  In other words, I don't want half of one image and half of another image in the viewport.

Seems pretty straightforward but I can't figure it out.  Part of the issue is that there doesn't seem to be an event to use for this purpose.  I know I can hook in to PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE or MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP/TouchEvent.TOUCH_END (which is what I'm doing now) but that event doesn't really give me what I need.

I really need an event that fires when the user releases the mouse as part of the scroll or lifts their finger off the device as part of the scroll.  ***And then I need to wait for the scroll to stop***.  For example, if I do a really fast swipe I need to wait for the scroller to stop or almost stop before I perform the snap.  The event fires as soon as I let go of the mouse or take my finger off the tablet, so if I alter the horizontal scroll pos then it gets overwritten by the "slowing down of the scroller".

By the way, I know I can use modulus logic to show each image "whole".  That's not where I'm stuck -- I'm stuck at which event to use to know WHEN to perform this mod logic.

Note that what I've already developed works just fine if I slowly scroll and then let off the mouse.  It's only when you slide more rapidly that it ceases to work.

Here's my partially working code:

```
private function onVehicleScrollerMouseUp(event:Event):void
{
    snapScroller();
}

private function onVehicleScrollerTouchEnd(event:Event):void
{
    snapScroller();
}

private function snapScroller():void
{
    // If the user didn't stop at an interval of 400, snap to that interval now
    var newScrollPosition:uint = vehicleScroller.viewport.horizontalScrollPosition as uint; 
    var modScrollPosition:uint = newScrollPosition % 400;
    var snapScrollPosition:uint;
    if (modScrollPosition == 0)
        snapScrollPosition = newScrollPosition;
    else
    {
        if (modScrollPosition <= 200)
            snapScrollPosition = newScrollPosition - modScrollPosition;
        else
            snapScrollPosition = newScrollPosition - modScrollPosition + 400; 
    }
    vehicleScroller.viewport.horizontalScrollPosition = snapScrollPosition as Number;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Matt, I have the exact same problem: Did you manage to solve it using the below solution or otherwise?

Comment: I've run into the same problem. Would love to know if you solved it!

Comment: link -> [AS3 Class (Extended Scroller)](http://mootricks.blogspot.com/2011/09/flex-snapscroller.html)

Answer (score 0):

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

Then listen to gesturePan and/or gestureSwipe events.

Answer (score 0):

The touchInteractionEnd event will dispatch after the user has released their finger and the scroll animation has stopped.  I ran into this issue when my page snapping broke randomly and needed to manually snap to some page.